# Signing Android apk?

Tags: android, authentication, apk

I was currently developing Android applications on a windows machine and signing with a "production.keystore" which I originally created on the windows machine. Now that I have migrated on Mac OS,can i use the old "production.keystore" or should I regenerate a new one? Will I still be able to sign the apk and release update on Android Market?
Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can still use that keystore. It's a universal format, as long as you keep that file and have a android SDK on that machine you can use it to sign your apk, independant of the platform you're using. (The android sdk tools will take care of that).

Comment: It's just a file thats easily movable :)

Answer (score 1):

Updates of your application are only possible if you sign with the same you used for initial publishing. So no, you should **not** generate new key. Use the existing one and keep it safe from harm - should you lose it, you will not be able to update your application anymore.

Comment: Thanks you very much .. will keep that securely :)

Answer (score 1):

I've been through this when moving from Win to linux. I was able to just copy the original keystore file over to your new machine and use that to continue to sign stuff. Eclipse/ADT will prompt you for a keytstore to use when you select Export Signed.

If you sign with a new keystore and try to upload the apk as an update to an existing app on Market it wont allow it.